# Angular Highcharts Custom Legend Label In Area Chart

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I've to customize label symbol in area chart type as it can done in line chart type:

**I've this code:**

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
        type: 'area'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
```

**My legend is like this:**
[image: Result]

**I expect to have this:**
[image]

I can't edit css style, this must be an exclusive customization for only this chart.

I'm using angular 7.2, I've imported Highchart with this:

```
import {Chart} from 'angular-highcharts';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by manually setting width and height of the legend symbols. You need to set `squareSymbol` to `false` to allow having different values for width and height:

```
legend: {
    squareSymbol: false,
    symbolHeight: 3,
    symbolWidth: 20
},
```

For example.

**EDIT**

If you want to align the symbol with text, use `useHTML: true` and set the `lineHeight`:

```
  legend: {
    useHTML: true,
    itemStyle: {
      lineHeight: "23px"
    },
    squareSymbol: false,
    symbolHeight: 3,
    symbolWidth: 20
  },
```

[See **updated** working jsfiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/twvmcro1/)

Comment: That works for the label, but for the tooltip is a fail.

Comment: It works, but how can I center the symbol with text ?

Comment: @Kabulan0lak perfect now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Swap the **area**.prototype.drawLegendSymbol method with **line**.prototype.drawLegendSymbol. This is enough in pure JS:

```
Highcharts.seriesTypes.area.prototype.drawLegendSymbol =
Highcharts.seriesTypes.line.prototype.drawLegendSymbol;
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6r307Lsw)

In angular you can wrap Highcharts this way:

```
(function(factory) {
  if (typeof module === "object" && module.exports) {
    module.exports = factory;
  } else {
    factory(Highcharts);
  }
})(function(Highcharts) {
  Highcharts.seriesTypes.area.prototype.drawLegendSymbol =
    Highcharts.seriesTypes.line.prototype.drawLegendSymbol;
});
```

docs: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#to-load-a-wrapper

Comment: Same here: That works for the label, but for the tooltip is a fail

Comment: For angular is not possible do this. I haven't `seriesTypes`

Comment: It is a default tooltip 'sign' even for a line or any other series. If you want to change this, you can do this in tooltip.formatter function line in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kcr1oynf
@Segamoto of course it is possible. I will edit my answer.